# Attempt to Assign Property 'email' of Non-object

Tags: php, laravel

May I know why the 'email' got the error? My table has an 'email' column.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $data->email = $request->email;
    $data->password = $request->password;
    $data->save();
}
```

Comment: `$data` would most likely be an array. Use `Log::info($data);`  and check your logs in `storage/logs/` to verify. It sounds like you're trying to save to an Eloquent model, so you'll have to retrieve it, assign the values to that, then save it.

Comment: if you are getting error for `mail` then there should be something wrong in the script because you column name is `email` not `mail`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to create a new user.

so, you need to create a new object

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = new User();
    $data->email = $request->email;
    $data->password = $request->password;
    $data->save();
}
```

Comment: and dont forget to encrypt the password. `$data->password = bcrypt($request->password);`

Comment: Yeah. This one will add as well.

Answer (score 5):

`$request->all()` returns an array of the request data, so you can't use the object accessor with it. It looks like you are trying to save data to the database, I would recommend looking at the documentation on eloquent models.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models